# Auditing changes to the audit log

Tags: ubuntu, audit, pci-dss, auditd

I have configured auditd for PCI compliance reasons

PCI states that existing logs cannot be changed without generating an alert

This article http://ptresearch.blogspot.com/2010/11/requirement-10-track-and-monitor-all.html recommends doing this:

-w /var/log/ -k Logs_Accessed -p rwxa

Will this auditctl command work? Surely you will end up in a circle with an audit event writing to the log provoking another audit event etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your audit command line will work perfectly. However, if you want some extra protection layers:

- use chattr to change your logs to be append only
- have a centralized logging server
- use SElinux rules to set up a rule enforcing only syslog and daemons themselves can write to /var/log
- use Unix permissions to make sure /var/log is accessible to only couple of people.

Comment: But if I audit write access to the audit.log file will this cause a loop?

Comment: It should be sensible enough not to chase its tail. Try it, see what happens.

Comment: Yes you are right it works. I was too timid to try it :(

Answer (score 1):

The section following that one in that article states that `"These messages are processed by daemon syslog, not auditd."`

Presumably, that means that the syslog daemon is configured to log those particular messages remotely rather than locally.

This is smart from a security perspective because if you log the fact that someone is altering a file in the same file that they are altering, they can simple remove that entry as well.  If you log them remotely, the attacker will have a harder time modifying them.   Remote logging of these messages also solves your edit-loop problem.

`auditd` may have an exception for itself that solves this loop problem but the authors may have just expected you not to create the loop in the first place.

Comment: I have a central syslog server where I send a copy of the audit.log entries. So perhaps I should just stick with that and not audit the audit.log?